# Error: Bad argument (Layer "crop" already was registered)

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network, tiff, canny-operator

##### The Problem

I have a problem when I am trying to automate a CNN Canny Edge detection pipeline, where many files are given as input and each is run through the Canny Edge detection CNN algorithm.

Here is the code that runs the algorithm on each given image (tiffs are in a folder, each should be processed using the CNN Canny algorithm):

```
files = get_files(TIF_DIR)
    for f in files:
        get_edges(f, OUT_DIR)
```

The code **successfully processes one image**, but subsequent attempts to process other images produces the error:

> OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
> OpenCV(4.0.1) Error: Bad argument (Layer "crop" already was registered) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20181221::LayerFactory::registerLayer, file C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp, line 3629

This is the function that I believe the error comes from. I have tried:

- making the three lines under 'setting up the layer' only run the first time the function is called, but the error persists.
- Using `cv.dnn_unregisterLayer('Crop')`, but the problem persists with the same error
- Renaming the Layer that I'm adding from 'Crop' to 'test', but the error stays the same. This leads me to think that **it may not be the layer that I am manually adding that is the problem**.

```
def get_edges(infile, outfolder):
    head_tail = os.path.split(infile)
    outpath = os.path.join(OUT_DIR, head_tail[1][:-3] + "_edge.png")
    if os.path.isfile(outpath):
        return 0

    cap = cv.VideoCapture(infile)
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()

    # Setting up layer
    cv.dnn_registerLayer('Crop', CropLayer)
    net = cv.dnn.readNet(os.path.abspath('deploy.prototxt'), os.path.abspath('hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel'))
    inp = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, scalefactor = 1.0, crop = False)

    # Outputting from net...
    net.setInput(inp)
    out = net.forward()
    out = out[0, 0]
    out = 255 * out
    out = out.astype(np.uint8)
    cv.imwrite(outpath, out)
```

Thanks for your help!

##### Specifications:

- Python version 3.8.5
- OpenCV version 4.0.1
- Windows 10.0.19042

Comment: How about calling `cv.dnn_unregisterLayer('Crop')` at the end of the function?

Comment: I was looking for a function like that, but now that you've told it to me and I've tried it, it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time so you probably resolved this long ago, but if anyone else faces this issue, I resolved it by simply moving `cv.dnn_registerLayer('Crop', CropLayer)` out of the function.
**Edit**: To provide more context: In my case I was running my app using fastAPI inside a Docker container, so everytime the program enters the function, it was trying to register the layer again. By moving that line out of the function we make sure that we only register the layer once when we start the program in the first place.

Comment: Could you give others (and the future you) additional details about **why** does it solve the problem?